Reverse singly linked list in C and return new head
Please, what am I missing?  I am trying to reverse a singly linked list (in-place), but all I get returned is the one node (pointer to the head of the list). I've tried using a void function (as a side effect) using the same logic in the while loop, but all give the same results.
previus_node is NULL, current_node points to head, while next_node points to head->next.
The while loop runs until current_node == NULL, for the first node, which should be the last, it points to NULL by saying current_node->next = previus_node (NULL initially), then setting previus_node as current_node to start the next iteration, followed by moving the current_node to current_node->next by one position forward.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node
{
    // holds number of type int
    int number;
    // holds pointer to node of the same type
    struct node *next;
} node;


// reverse link list
node *reverse(node *);

// create new node
node *create_node(int );

void print_list(node *head);

int main(void)
{
    // declare head node
    node *head = NULL;
    
    int numb2[] = {2,3,1,4,0,9,7};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(numb2) / sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        head = insert_begining(head, create_node(numb2[i]));
    }        
    
    head = reverse(head);
    
    print_list(head);

    // free pointers
    destroy(head);
 }

// create linked list and return pointer to the list head
node *create_node(int n)
{
    // 1 dynamically allocate space for new node (linked list) of type node *
    node *new = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    // 2 check to make sure we didin run out of memory
    if (new == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    // 3 init nodes value field
    new->number = n;
    // 4 init nodes next field
    new->next = NULL;
    // 5 return pointer to a newly created node*
    return new;
}

// prints link list
void print_list(node *head)
{
    // TODO print in asc and desc
    // print elements of link list
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL");
    }
    // else not NULL
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%i, ", head->number);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");



// reverse list
node *reverse(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    
    node *previus_node = NULL;
    node *current_node = head;
    
    
    while (current_node != NULL)
    {
        current_node->next = previus_node;
        previus_node = current_node;
        
        // move current node forward by 1
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }
    
    return head;
}


You already treat your list as a stack. Continue with that... To reverse the list, "pop" every node from the list and "push" into a second list.

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem. Your posted code does not compile, because it is calling the undefined function insert_begining.

You are missing a } in print_list() so you never compiled the code you posted.  Also, you refer to functions that you didn't include insert_beginning() and destroy()[

You do node *previus_node = NULL;, then in the while loop's first iteration, current_node->next = previus_node; and then current_node = current_node->next. What do you suppose current_node points to now? Also, you return the same head value that you got passed in.

You simply need three pointers, prev, curr and next and these four statements, while curr != NULL, and finally return the prev:
node *next = curr->next;
curr->next = prev;
prev = curr;
curr = next;


node *next = curr->next;: prior to changing the curr->next pointer, we should save the address of the next node in the next var.
curr->next = prev;: here we reverse the direction of the curr node's pointer.
prev = curr;: we update the prev node to be the curr node.
curr = next;: we update the curr node to be the next node.

Code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
  int number;
  struct node *next;
} node;

node *reverse(node *head);
node *create_node(int n);
void display(node *head);
node *add_node(node *head, node *node);
void destroy(node *head);

node *create_node(int n) {
  node *new = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  if (new == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  new->number = n;
  new->next = NULL;
  return new;
}

void display(node *head) {
  while (head != NULL) {
    printf("%i\t", head->number);
    head = head->next;
  }
  printf("\n\n");
}

node *reverse(node *head) {
  node *prev = NULL;
  node *curr = head;
  while (curr != NULL) {
    node *next = curr->next;
    curr->next = prev;
    prev = curr;
    curr = next;
  }
  return prev;
}

node *add_node(node *head, node *node) {
  node->next = head;
  return node;
}

void destroy(node *head) {
  while (head != NULL) {
    node *temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  node *head = NULL;
  int nums[] = {2, 3, 1, 4, 0, 9, 7};

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(nums) / sizeof(int); i++) {
    head = add_node(head, create_node(nums[i]));
  }

  display(head);
  head = reverse(head);
  display(head);
  destroy(head);
}

Prints
7   9   0   4   1   3   2   

2   3   1   4   0   9   7


thanks, i should return previus_node, not head.

@AbuAminu Right. Because after reversing all nodes, the prev node is the last node and therefore the prev node is the head of reversed list.

For starters this if statement in the function reverse
if (head == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}

is redundant.
Within the function the pointer head is not even being changed.
In the first and actually single iteration of the while loop
while (current_node != NULL)
{
    current_node->next = previus_node;
    previus_node = current_node;
    
    // move current node forward by 1
    current_node = current_node->next;
}

the data member next of the node pointed to by the pointer head is set to NULL due to these statements
node *previus_node = NULL; // <===
node *current_node = head;


while (current_node != NULL)
{
    current_node->next = previus_node; // <===
    //...

As a result all other nodes of the original list are lost.
Using your function declaration it can be defined the following way
node * reverse(node *head)
{
    node *current_node = head;
    head = NULL;
    
    while ( current_node != NULL )
    {
        node *previous_head = head;
        head = current;
        current = current->next;
        head->next = previous_head;
    }

    return head;
}

